# Detecting camera raw image saturation/clipping level

Tags: image-processing, sensor, camera

I'm looking for a fast but robust algorithm to detect whether a camera raw image has clipped/saturated highlights and, if so, compute the level at which saturation occurs. This saturation/clipping level is called the white level. For the purposes of my question, a camera raw image can be assumed to be a two dimensional 16-bit grayscale image.

I have scoured the <strike>Galaxy</strike> Google Scholar for solutions to this problem. In papers dealing with a sensor white level, this value is assumed to be known a-priori. Or it is assumed that it can/will be manually identified. The consensus "solution" seems to be to manually inspect a histogram of the image levels for a sharp tail edge—a bin on the "right side" of the histogram with many more pixels than the bins in its "neighborhood". However, reducing that approach to a machine algorithm providing exact values of "edge", "right side" and "neighborhood" is not exactly straightforward.

My current, extremely janky and mathematically uninformed approach is to look for a location in the histogram where the difference in successive bin pixel count is greater than 10,000, starting from the right side of this histogram, bounded below by 12,000. This does not account for the global distribution or density of pixel values.

I understand there will always be images with ambiguous answers to this question—images with a "small" tail edge in the histogram, for some definition of "small" and "tail". What I'm looking for is some kind of robust mathematical/statistical approach with a small/single set of meaningful parameters that can be adjusted to tune precision/recall. I suspect there's some kind of image transformation that can help with this, but with which I'm unfamiliar. Any thoughts?

Comment: correct me, but clipping *always* happens at the maximum value?

Comment: @MarcusMüller What do you mean by maximum value?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Theoretically, a sensor can be in analog clipping/saturation without the ADC clipping. This seems unlikely and like a design flaw, but is possible nonetheless.

Comment: This would spread the clipping across several values, somewhere below the digital maximum.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Strictly speaking, a pixel at the maximum (or saturation) value may correspond to an actual brightness level in the scene, but we can assume for the sake of this exercise that any pixel value at the saturation level is in fact a clipped (or lost) value.